# Remove unused CSS in Angular using PurgeCSS

Tags: css, angular, css-purge, purgecss

I am having issues when removing unused CSS using PurgeCSS (webpack plugin) on my Angular 16 process build process. I can get my final CSS minimized but it seems it is not done fully because when I inspect the generated I get things like variables and other classes being injected so that the end file is bigger than it should be.

My current configuration is `webpack.config.js`:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const { PurgeCSSPlugin } = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
      plugins: [
        new PurgeCSSPlugin({ 
          paths: glob.sync('./src/**/*', { nodir: true }),
          safelist: {
            standard: [/^leaflet-/]
          }
        })
      ]
    };
```

I have the `custom-webpack` in my `angular.json`:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/ads.txt",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/",
                "output": "./assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles-fonts.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "webpack.config.js"
            }
          },
```

In my styles.scss I do have the following imports:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
```

And the final file size is 30Kb which is OK. That however I think is bigger than it should be because I don't have much CSS in my code. Anyway, looking at different posts or even the official documentation of the package (https://purgecss.com/plugins/webpack.html#options), if I do:

```
const { PurgeCSSPlugin } = require("purgecss-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob");
const PATHS = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
};

// In the webpack configuration
new PurgeCSSPlugin({
  paths: glob.sync(`${PATHS.src}/**/*`, { nodir: true }),
});
```

Then I get a styles.css of 6KB which I say it's about right (between 6-15KB I would say it would be correct) and it's got some bootstrap css in it, however when I deploy it then the styles are messed up, so thought that `path` is wrong.

Then I tried setting up a `postbuild` process using `purgecss` like this:

```
const { PurgeCSS } = require('purgecss');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    console.log('Removing unused CSS from files...');

    const purgecss = await new PurgeCSS().purge({
      content: ['./dist/browser/*.html', './dist/browser/*.js'],
      css: ["./dist/browser/*.css"],
      safelist: {
        standard: [/^leaflet-/]
      },
      variables: true
    });

    purgecss.map(({css, file}) => {
        console.log(file);
        fs.writeFileSync(file, css);
    });
})();
```

and I got around 30Kbs as well. I noticed that flags like `keyframes` do remove them from the final CSS but the `variables` don't seem to have any effect and all of them are present in the file. Why is that? Is there another way to set it up to get the truly only-used CSS outputted?

I'm using `Angular v16.2.2` and `PurgeCSS v5.0.0`